# dimmer switch for both low voltage LED and leading edge at the same time?

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I'm installing LED ceiling lights that come with analog low voltage control for dimming (i.e., 4 wire). However there is one existing sconce light that I hope to not replace. Would like it to also dim, but using 2 wire, leading edge control. I see a controller that offers all three types of controls but there appears to be toggle switches to select which. I'd like both simultaneously. Hoping the black is leading edge simultaneous with the low voltage. Basically don't know if the four wire control black is on continuously or leading edge switched.

The sconce is a standard screw in bulb socket. Currently with common CFI but the plan would be to switch to a dimmable LED bulb able to work on leading edge.

Yes, the analog low voltage is 0-10v (analog 4 wire).

Comment: Can I presume that said "analog low voltage control" is a 0-10V control?

Comment: Also, what is the sconce light wired to already?

Comment: Seems to me like you'll likely have issues with dimming rates, especially if the sconce is not LED with a similar driver.

Comment: @Tyson -- I think his best bet would be to use a regular dimmer and then use a dimmed hot -> 0-10V converter to drive the 0-10V(?) inputs on the LED driver

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a garden-variety incandescent dimmer, connect the sconce light to it directly, then connect a [Lutron GRX-TVI](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/032119b.eng.pdf) to it and use it to provide 0-10V to the LED driver.

Comment: Was not aware of the Lutron GRX-TVI product. Looks like a very interesting approach. I'll look seriously at it.

Comment: Yes, it does look like that'd do the job. For residential, the $200 (amazon) price seems a bit steep, but at the moment appears to be the best option and there appear to be more competitive pricing other the the headline item.